# ListActivity layout not having margins around

Tags: android, android-layout

**EDIT: The problem seems to be with:**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

within the OnCreate... but don't know why...

I have this code:

```
public class BluetoothDiscovery extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String MAC = this.discoveredPrinters.get(position);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("mac", MAC);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

    // Finalizamos el Activity
    finish();
}

private ArrayList<String> discoveredPrinters = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
private static DiscoveryHandler btDiscoveryHandler = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    // Configuramos el theme del activity
    Utils.setCustomTheme(this, getApplicationContext(), true);        

    setContentView(R.layout.discovery_results);
    ---
```

The layout xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
>  

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No printers found" 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
```

But I cannot see why the title is so close to the borders of the activity. Just in case it is necessary, the Manifest expresses this activity this way:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".printing.BluetoothDiscovery"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

This is how the activity is invoked from the preferences:

```
public class AdjustmentsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

....
....

    etPRINTER = (Preference) findPreference("key_select_printer");
    etPRINTER.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            String PrinterMAC = Utils
                    .ObtenerMACPrinterSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

            Intent intentLocatePrinter = new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(), BluetoothDiscovery.class);

            intentLocatePrinter.putExtra("titulo",
                    "Búsqueda de impresora Bluetooth");

            startActivityForResult(intentLocatePrinter,
                    REQUEST_SELECTED_PRINTER);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And next is what I visually obtain which is somewhat weird due to a lack of margings around the whole view. My question is where is my problem located (Manifest, xml, class)?.

Thanks in advance,

Jose.

[image: This is what I see]

Comment: Try to add this android:padding="10dp" properties to ListView.

Comment: Will have a look at it when in front of my computer. Thanks a lot for the response. How didn't I check this before?

Comment: It didn't work. The only different thing for this activity is that the intent comes from the preferences screen by using setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()...